# Passar uma struct como parametro

Tags: c++, dll

Preciso que essa struct

```
typedef struct _wfs_ptr_retract_bins
{
    WORD                 wRetractBin;
    USHORT               usRetractCount;
} WFSPTRRETRACTBINS, *LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS;
```

Vire um parametro que irei colocar aqui.

```
typedef struct _wfs_ptr_status
{
...
LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS *lppRetractBins;
} WFSPTRSTATUS, *LPWFSPTRSTATUS;
```

Como faço ?

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
WFSPTRSTATUS PtrStatus;
LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS RetractBins;

RetractBins->wRetractBin = WFS_PTR_RETRACTBININSERTED;
RetractBins->usRetractCount = 0;

PtrStatus.lppRetractBins = &RetractBins;//AQUI QUERO PASSAR
```

Comment: Ainda falta contexto do que está fazendo. Isso que tentou não está dando certo?

Comment: Ele n acusa erro de compilação, porém sei que não funciona.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o erro. Dê informações completas pra gente poder ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nenhum objeto foi criado e você está modificando os membros da struct por um ponteiro que não aponta para nada. Isto é comportamento indefinido.

O erro está em:

```
LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS RetractBins;

RetractBins->wRetractBin = WFS_PTR_RETRACTBININSERTED;
RetractBins->usRetractCount = 0;
```

Aqui `RetractBins` é um ponteiro `_wfs_ptr_retract_bins` que aponta para nenhum objeto.

O certo é primeiramente criar um objeto `WFSPTRRETRACTBINS` e então passar o seu endereço de memória para o ponteiro `RetractBins`.

O código correto seria: *(sem utilizar **windows.h**)*

```
#include <iostream>

#define WFS_PTR_RETRACTBININSERTED 5

typedef unsigned short USHORT;
typedef unsigned short WORD;

typedef struct _wfs_ptr_retract_bins
{
    WORD                 wRetractBin;
    USHORT               usRetractCount;
} WFSPTRRETRACTBINS, *LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS;

typedef struct _wfs_ptr_status
{
LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS *lppRetractBins;
} WFSPTRSTATUS, *LPWFSPTRSTATUS;



int main()
{
    WFSPTRSTATUS PtrStatus;
    WFSPTRRETRACTBINS objRetractBins; //primeiro criar um objeto válido na memoria
    LPWFSPTRRETRACTBINS RetractBins;

    RetractBins = &objRetractBins; // agora sim, o ponteiro RetractBins aponta para um objeto

    RetractBins->wRetractBin = WFS_PTR_RETRACTBININSERTED;
    RetractBins->usRetractCount = 15;

    PtrStatus.lppRetractBins = &RetractBins;//AQUI QUERO PASSAR

    std::cout << (*PtrStatus.lppRetractBins)->wRetractBin << std::endl; //lppRetractBins é um ponteiro para ponteiro, é necessário dereferencialo.

}
```